# Lasso regression objective did not converge

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, cross-validation, lasso-regression

Here is my code. When I run it the ridge is fine, however for the lasso I get the error message:

```
ConvergenceWarning: Objective did not converge. You might want to increase the number of iterations.
```

Please help.

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression, Lasso, Ridge, RidgeCV, LassoCV
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
import numpy as np
import sys

dataset = np.loadtxt(sys.argv[1], delimiter = ',')
X = dataset[:,:10]
y = dataset[:,10]

ridge_cv = RidgeCV(alphas=[1e-3, 1e-2, 1e-1, 1, 10, 100]).fit(X,y)

lasso_cv = LassoCV(alphas=[1e-3, 1e-2, 1e-1, 1, 10, 100]).fit(X,y)

lin_reg = LinearRegression()
ridge_reg = Ridge(alpha = ridge_cv.alpha_)
lasso_reg = Lasso(alpha = lasso_cv.alpha_)

print(cross_val_score(lin_reg, X, y, cv=2).mean())
print(cross_val_score(ridge_reg, X, y, cv=2).mean())
print(cross_val_score(lasso_reg, X, y, cv=2).mean())
```

Answer (score -1):

**Increase tolerance.**

Check [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Lasso.html) *The tolerance for the optimization: if the updates are smaller than tol, the optimization code checks the dual gap for optimality and continues until it is smaller than tol*

Bascially responsible for convergence

Comment: Please don't post a comment as an answer unless you test and see that your suggestion, with specific code, answers the question. Your post is merely an untested suggestion at the moment.

Comment: Fair point, sorry. I am 80% sure its correct. How do you expect to replicate without dataset, thats whats convergence dependent.